# How to find folder path of a mailbox using folderId?

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010, ews-managed-api

I have the folderId property of a folder in a mailbox. How do I find the full path of the folder using EWS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `PR_FOLDER_PATHNAME` extended property which should contain the full path. Example:

```
ExtendedPropertyDefinition FolderPath = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(0x66B5, MapiPropertyType.String);
PropertySet psset1 = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties);
psset1.Add(FolderPath);

Folder FolderwithPath = Folder.Bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, psset1);
Object FolderPathVal = null;
if (FolderwithPath.TryGetProperty(FolderPath,out  FolderPathVal))
{
    Console.WriteLine(FolderPathVal);
}
```

Comment: Hey Glen... Just want to let you know that I am not picking on you. I am doing a lot of reading of EWS API code and you keep coming up. Keep up the good work.

Comment: How did you find that Extended Property tag `0x66B5` and its associated name/description? I've been searching for documentation on those, but I'm coming up empty.